# How to update mapping on elasticsearch along with exiting fields

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-mapping

`How to add two new fields into exiting template on Elasticsearch

Below is current template

```
curl -XGET 'http://endpoint_name/_template/es_template_dev?pretty'{"voice_incoming_es_template_dev" : {"order" : 0,"index_patterns" : ["data_dev*"],"settings" : {"index" : {"number_of_shards" : "1"}},"mappings" : {"es_template_dev" : {"properties" : {"id" : {"type" : "long"},"unqid_es" : {"type" : "keyword"},"id_call" : {"type" : "keyword"},"parent_id" : {"type" : "keyword"
```

```
  }
  }
},
"aliases" : { }
```

```
}}}
```

I am getting below error

```
curl -XPUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" "http:endpoint/mapping/es_data_dev/"  -d '{"properties": {"duration": {"type": "integer"},"duration_agents": {"type": "integer"}}}'{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting mapping update to [2022_09] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [bd_stg, 20230301]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting mapping update to [voice_summary_obd_stg_2022_09] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [voice_stg, es_data_dev_20230301]"},"status":400}`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily update your mapping with Kibana UI.

[image]